# Ruby gem Letter Opener

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm new to ruby on rails and trying to use the Ruby gem 'letter opener. I've followed tutorials on the set up process but am a little confused on the 'default from' and 'default to' values for the emails.

default (:from => "", :to=>"")

Can't I set any email value for from and to? I keep getting errors whenever I try using the tutorials email inputs or my own. Im still new so not sure if I am even asking the right question.

Comment: What error are you getting? What tutorial are you looking at?  Did you look at the `ActionMailer` documentation (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)

Answer (score 1):

There are two lines to be added in `config/environments/development.rb` put before `end` in the file:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :letter_opener
```

`from` can be used for any email and `to` is used to where email is to be send. Both should be valid email addresses.

You can leave default and create your own mailer and call the function like this:

```
mail(from: "NAME<EMAIL>", subject: 'YOUR SUBJECT', to: "NAME<EMAIL>").deliver_now
```